# Divide a list (or vector) of columns by a list (or vector of constants)

Tags: r, data.table

I want to divide a dynamically created list of column names (or vector) (`vlist`) by a dynamically created list of constants (denList). So every element in the first column in the column list is divided by the first constant in the constant list, etc. The code below sets up a data table with two columns and creates two variables with constants. The last line is my attempt to do the dividing but fails. Help on solving what seem like it ought to be a simple problem greatly appreciated.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(v1 = runif(10), v2 = runif(10))
v1Den <- 10
v2Den <- 20
denList <- as.vector(c("v1Den", "v2Den"))
vlist <- as.vector(c("v1", "v2"))
ratioList <- as.vector(c("V1rat", "V2rat"))

DT[,(ratioList) := Map(`/`, mget(vlist), mget(denList))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the `envir` for 'denList' as `.GlobalEnv`

```
DT[,(ratioList) := Map(`/`, mget(vlist), mget(denList, envir = .GlobalEnv))]
DT
#          v1         v2      V1rat       V2rat
#1: 0.7259460 0.12956933 0.07259460 0.006478467
#2: 0.8867084 0.07180409 0.08867084 0.003590204
#3: 0.3466163 0.46579134 0.03466163 0.023289567
#4: 0.2764356 0.02441249 0.02764356 0.001220625
#5: 0.7028396 0.71207397 0.07028396 0.035603699
#6: 0.9035681 0.51862505 0.09035681 0.025931252
#7: 0.1842809 0.78817567 0.01842809 0.039408784
#8: 0.1215719 0.95116182 0.01215719 0.047558091
#9: 0.8056753 0.39964896 0.08056753 0.019982448
#10:0.2990145 0.87846840 0.02990145 0.043923420
```

---

Or another option is `set`

```
for(j in seq_along(vlist)){
 set(DT, i = NULL, j = ratioList[j], value =  DT[[vlist[j]]]/get(denList[j]))
}
```

Comment: Fixed the typos in the original post.